# How to build a p2 site for the Eclipse delta pack?

Tags: eclipse, p2, tycho, delta-pack

I am trying to build my own p2 update site for the Eclipse delta site (since it is not available as p2 update site).

What I did:

```
 # Get the delta pack from Eclipse web site
 #
 wget http://mirror.cc.columbia.edu/pub/software/eclipse/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.7.2-201202080800/eclipse-3.7.2-delta-pack.zip

 # Unzip in its own directory (delta)
 #
 mkdir delta
 cd delta
 unzip ../eclipse-3.7.2-delta-pack.zip
 cd ../

 # Get Eclipse from Eclipse web site (in theory we could only get equinox,
 # but in pratice, it refused to start due to some race conditions.  Using
 # eclipse works out-of-the-box)
 #
 wget http://mirror.cc.columbia.edu/pub/software/eclipse/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.7.2-201202080800/eclipse-3.7.2-delta-pack.zip

 # Untar Eclipse (it creates an "eclipse" directory)
 #
 tar xzvf eclipse-java-indigo-SR2-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz

 # Create (publish) a p2 site out of the delta features/plugins
 #
 ./eclipse/eclipse -console -consolelog -nosplash -debug -verbose        \
    -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.FeaturesAndBundlesPublisher       \
    -metadataRepository file:${Repository}  \
    -artifactRepository file:${Repository}  \
    -source delta/eclipse                   \
    -configs ANY            \
    -publishArtifacts
```

That creates in `${Repository}` the following structure:

```
/<...>/local/apache2/htdocs/delta
    |-- artifacts.xml
    |-- content.xml
    |-- features
    |   `-- org.eclipse.equinox.executable_3.5.1.v20111216-1653-7P7NFUIFIbaUcU77s0KQWHw5HZTZ.jar
    `-- plugins
        |-- org.eclipse.compare.win32.source_1.0.200.I20110510-0800.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.compare.win32_1.0.200.I20110510-0800.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.core.filesystem.aix.ppc_1.1.0.v20110423-0524.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.core.filesystem.hpux.ia64_32_1.0.100.v20110423-0524.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.core.filesystem.linux.x86_1.4.0.v20110423-0524.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.core.filesystem.linux.x86_64_1.2.0.v20110423-0524.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.core.filesystem.macosx_1.3.0.v20110423-0524.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.core.filesystem.solaris.sparc_1.2.0.v20110423-0524.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.core.filesystem.win32.x86_1.1.300.v20110423-0524.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.core.filesystem.win32.x86_64_1.1.300.v20110423-0524.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.core.net.linux.x86_1.1.200.I20110419-0800.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.core.net.linux.x86_64_1.1.0.I20110331-0827.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.core.net.win32.x86_1.0.100.I20110331-0827.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.core.net.win32.x86_64_1.0.100.I20110331-0827.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.core.resources.win32.x86_3.5.100.v20110423-0524.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.carbon.macosx_1.1.100.v20110502.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_1.1.101.v20120109-1504.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx_1.1.101.v20120109-1504.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.aix.ppc64_1.1.0.v20110530.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.aix.ppc_1.1.0.v20110530.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.hpux.ia64_32_1.0.0.v20110502.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.ppc64_1.0.100.v20110505.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.s390x_1.1.100.v20110505.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.1.100.v20110505.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.100.v20110505.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.solaris.sparc_1.1.100.v20110505.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.solaris.x86_1.1.100.v20110505.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.100.v20110502.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.100.v20110502.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.equinox.security.macosx.source_1.100.100.v20100503.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.equinox.security.macosx_1.100.100.v20100503.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.equinox.security.win32.x86.source_1.0.200.v20100503.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.equinox.security.win32.x86_1.0.200.v20100503.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.equinox.security.win32.x86_64.source_1.0.0.v20110502.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.equinox.security.win32.x86_64_1.0.0.v20110502.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.jdt.launching.macosx.source_3.2.100.v20111006_r372.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.jdt.launching.macosx_3.2.100.v20111006_r372.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.jdt.launching.ui.macosx.source_1.0.100.v20111006_r372.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.jdt.launching.ui.macosx_1.0.100.v20111006_r372.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.swt.carbon.macosx.source_3.7.2.v3740f.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.swt.carbon.macosx_3.7.2.v3740f.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.source_3.7.2.v3740f.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64.source_3.7.2.v3740f.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_3.7.2.v3740f.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx_3.7.2.v3740f.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.swt.gtk.aix.ppc.source_3.7.2.v3740f.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.swt.gtk.aix.ppc64.source_3.7.2.v3740f.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.swt.gtk.aix.ppc64_3.7.2.v3740f.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.swt.gtk.aix.ppc_3.7.2.v3740f.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.swt.gtk.hpux.ia64_32.source_3.7.2.v3740f.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.swt.gtk.hpux.ia64_32_3.7.2.v3740f.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.ppc64.source_3.7.2.v3740f.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.ppc64_3.7.2.v3740f.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.s390.source_3.7.2.v3740f.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.s390_3.7.2.v3740f.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.s390x.source_3.7.2.v3740f.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.s390x_3.7.2.v3740f.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86.source_3.7.2.v3740f.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_3.7.2.v3740f.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64.source_3.7.2.v3740f.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64_3.7.2.v3740f.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.swt.gtk.solaris.sparc.source_3.7.2.v3740f.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.swt.gtk.solaris.sparc_3.7.2.v3740f.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.swt.gtk.solaris.x86.source_3.7.2.v3740f.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.swt.gtk.solaris.x86_3.7.2.v3740f.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86.source_3.7.2.v3740f.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_3.7.2.v3740f.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64.source_3.7.2.v3740f.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64_3.7.2.v3740f.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.ui.carbon.source_4.0.100.I20101109-0800.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.ui.carbon_4.0.100.I20101109-0800.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.ui.cocoa.source_1.1.0.I20101109-0800.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.ui.cocoa_1.1.0.I20101109-0800.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.ui.win32.source_3.2.200.v20110928-1505.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.ui.win32_3.2.200.v20110928-1505.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.update.core.linux.source_3.2.200.v20100512.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.update.core.linux_3.2.200.v20100512.jar
        |-- org.eclipse.update.core.win32.source_3.2.200.v20100512.jar
        `-- org.eclipse.update.core.win32_3.2.200.v20100512.jar
```

which I can check using an URL http://my.server/delta.

When I add the url in my parent pom:

```
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                    <id>delta</id>
                    <layout>p2</layout>
                    <url>http://my.server/delta</url>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                    <id>eclipse-platform</id>
                    <layout>p2</layout>
                    <url>http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo</url>
            </repository>
```

It does not pick up the plugins my project needs:

```
[INFO] Cannot complete the request.  Generating details.
[INFO] Cannot complete the request.  Generating details.
[INFO] {osgi.ws=win32, osgi.os=win32, osgi.arch=x86_64, org.eclipse.update.install.features=true}
[ERROR] Cannot resolve project dependencies:
[ERROR]   Software being installed: com.example.fs 1.0.0.qualifier
[ERROR]   Missing requirement: com.example.fs 1.0.0.qualifier requires 'org.eclipse.ui.carbon 0.0.0' but it could not be found
```

The plugin org.eclipse.ui.carbon is in the generated contents.xml and artifacts.xml files and also in the plugins directory:

```
/<...>/local/apache2/htdocs/delta
    |-- artifacts.xml
    |-- content.xml
    |-- features
    `-- plugins
```

I am not sure why maven cannot get the plugin from the update site.  How can I debug/fix this ?

Comment: What do you need in the delta pack? I'm pretty sure you can use http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.2, uncategorize, and look for the exectuable action.

Comment: As Ian mentioned, all of the things in the delta pack are available from .../eclipse/updates/3.7 or .../releases/indigo (4.2 and juno are the latest release)

Comment: You are correct The Eclipse Platform Launchers is available in the /eclipse/updates/x.y.  I missed it because by default the Software Updates dialog has the "Group by category" checked.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I talked too soon.  While the update site /eclipse/updates/3.7 has the "Eclipse Platform Launchers" I do not see how to get for all platforms.

I did get the "Eclipse Platform Launchers" but now my product is missing the following plugin.  We need those plugins to build the product for several platforms:

```
<plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.carbon.macosx" fragment="true"/>
<plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx" fragment="true"/>
<plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64" fragment="true"/>
<plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.gtk.aix.ppc" fragment="true"/>
<plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.gtk.aix.ppc64" fragment="true"/>
<plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.gtk.hpux.ia64_32" fragment="true"/>
<plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.ppc64" fragment="true"/>
<plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.s390" fragment="true"/>
<plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.s390x" fragment="true"/>
<plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86" fragment="true"/>
<plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64" fragment="true"/>
<plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.gtk.solaris.sparc" fragment="true"/>
<plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.gtk.solaris.x86" fragment="true"/>
<plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86" fragment="true"/>
```

That the reason why I initially used the delta pack in the first place.

I guess the question was more:  How do you build a product for several platforms using Software Updates sites only ?

Comment: I found out that tycho can find those plugins in the repo `eclipse/updates/3.7` thru the feature `org.eclipse.equinox.executable`, but you need to add the `os/ws/arch` in your product definition file.  So instead of:
    `<plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64" fragment="true"/>`

you will put:

    `<plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64" fragment="true" os="macosx" ws="cocoa" arch="x86_64"/>`

Answer (score 2):

The Delta Pack contents are already available in the "Eclipse Project Updates" update site (e.g. http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.3 for Kepler). Just include the feature groups *Eclipse RCP* and *Equinox Target Components* in your target platform.